# SettingNotFoundException: com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been getting this error:

```
android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: bt_svcst_com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService
    at android.provider.Settings$System.getIntForUser(Settings.java:1358)
        at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Settings.java:1348)
        at com.broadcom.bt.service.ProfileConfig.isProfileConfiguredEnabled(ProfileConfig.java:375)
        at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService.setProfileServiceState(AdapterService.java:791)
        at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService.processStart(AdapterService.java:557)
        at com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterState$OffState.processMessage(AdapterState.java:159)
        at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:966)
        at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

and have no idea where it's coming from, since it doesn't point to any of my code in the stack trace.
I looked at the [`Settings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) page on Android Developers, and it says that

> The `Settings` provider contains global system-level device preferences.

Since it says "system-level" preferences, does that mean I shouldn't have to worry about it? My connections are all failing when I try and connect to a device.